# Restore functionality for paid application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am going to upload an iphone app with in-app purchase. Previously i had made this application paid. Now i am going to make it free with in-app. Now the users which have already downloaded the app needs not to do that in-app purchase part. How is this possible?

Comment: They must not update to the newer version , otherwise they will have to buy it using in app purchase

Comment: Thanks..Apart from there their is no other option?

Comment: No, there is no other options for this. As existing user will update app, they also have to do in-App purchase

Comment: Ok thanks for help RahulGupta and Mutawe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If existing user will download updated version, then he has to upgrade app by paying through In-App purchase.

There is no such facility if user updates the application.